# How to fix my footer background image to be always visible on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, mobile, background, footer

My website is https://www.pisqueya.com

I have a big background image full width always visible at the bottom of all pages, it's working fine on desktop but not on mobile device.

Anyone know what I'm missing with my code below to fix that please?

```css
body {
  font-family: portuguesa;
  background: url(https://www.pisqueya.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/footer-pisqueya.png) no-repeat center bottom fixed;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fdeae1;
}

#wrapper,
#main {
  background-color: initial!Important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to know which elements you're trying to target / exclude. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: please create a code snippet of your code and your image is visible on the mobile. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change Your CSS

```
body {
    font-family: portuguesa;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
/*Add This CSS*/
    body::after {
        background: url(https://www.pisqueya.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/footer-pisqueya.png) no-repeat center bottom fixed #fdeae1;
        content: "";
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-size: contain;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys but after trying all your solutions, it's not working :(
You can check my code source to see that I've applied the CSS but there no change on the frontend for mobile :(

Comment: I have checked on google chrome with iPhone-6/7/8 working fine

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, For me It's not working on S7+  Chrome and Samsung browser :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine for me.
The thing is when you are in a smaller screen the picture is getting small too.

If you want to use the same picture you should change the value of background-size for mobile devices or use a different picture for them.

Hope it can be usefull too.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries for mobile device. Add media query CSS for mobile device size and put your CSS Code in it. Following code will help you.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:200px)
{
   body {
   font-family: portuguesa;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
 }

 body::after {
    background: url(https://www.pisqueya.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/footer-pisqueya.png) no-repeat center bottom fixed #fdeae1;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```